# Access Problem with \bin\x86\Debug\AppX\Assets\

Tags: c#, file, uwp, access-denied

the situation is as follows:
I want to put pictures i get to a file in my assets.
I want to get the folder with:

```
StorageFolder folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
```

and the create a file there with:

```
File.Create(folder.Path + @"\" + "Assets" + @"\" + storageItem.DisplayName + storageItem.FileType);
```

But it throws an System.UnauthorizedAccessException at me when i try to create the file. I need a permanent fix for this as other users (some without administrative powers) will need to use the program i am writing.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's correct because you can not alter or create something in installed dir only option available to this dir is reading files that exist there.

if you want to keep some file in-app local or temp directory then you can use

AppliacationData.Currunt.LocalFolder/TemproryFolder etc to keep your file

Answer (score 1):

Its likely your current directory is set to somewhere which required administrator permission. You can change your current directory:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory?view=netcore-3.1

The below looks like a fairly solid overview on where you should store things and has plenty of code examples

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/370232/Where-should-I-store-my-data

Comment: Thank you verry much, sadly the 'easy' way shown in the overview which should be always accessible returs an ```System.IO.FileNotFoundException``` (```Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)```) which confuses me, because these special Folders should exist?

Comment: @JL_Funk Environment.GetFolderPath shouldn't throw a file not found exception. Can you post the full line of code?

Comment: Strangely enugh, it doesn't anymore. But it could not have been annything else since it was this line that threw the error: ```var test = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);```